# Create Google Contact --> Why Only "NAME" not inserted in new contact?

Tags: php, oauth, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-api-client

**Here is what I have made request** :-

```
    // create new entry
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->formatOutput = true;

$entry = $doc->createElement('atom:entry');
$entry->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:atom', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
$entry->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:gd', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');
$doc->appendChild($entry);

$cat = $doc->createElement('atom:category');
$cat->setAttribute('scheme', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind');
$cat->setAttribute('term', 'http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact');
$entry->appendChild($cat);

// add name element
$name = $doc->createElement('gd:name');
$entry->appendChild($name);
$givenName = $doc->createElement('gd:givenName', $_POST['fname']);
$familyName = $doc->createElement('gd:familyName', $_POST['lname']);
$fullName = $doc->createElement('gd:fullName', $_POST['fname'] . $_POST['lname']);
$name->appendChild($givenName);
$name->appendChild($familyName);
$name->appendChild($fullName);

$content = $doc->createElement('atom:content', 'Notes');
$content->setAttribute('type', 'text');
$entry->appendChild($content);
// add email element
$email = $doc->createElement('gd:email');
$entry->appendChild($email);
$email->setAttribute('address', $_POST['email_id']);
$email->setAttribute('displayName', $_POST['fname']);
$email->setAttribute('primary', 'true');
$email->setAttribute('rel', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work');

// add im element
$im = $doc->createElement('gd:im');
$entry->appendChild($im);
$im->setAttribute('address', $_POST['email_id']);
$im->setAttribute('protocol', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#GOOGLE_TALK');
$im->setAttribute('primary', 'true');
$im->setAttribute('rel', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home');
// add phone element
$ph = $doc->createElement('gd:phoneNumber', $_POST['phone']);
$entry->appendChild($ph);
$ph->setAttribute('rel', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home');

//insert Address
$address = $doc->createElement('gd:structuredPostalAddress');
$address->setAttribute('primary', 'true');
$address->setAttribute('rel', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work');
$entry->appendChild($address);
$postal = $doc->createElement('gd:postcode', $_POST['postal']);
$country = $doc->createElement('gd:country', $_POST['country']);
$fulladd = $doc->createElement('gd:formattedAddress', $_POST['address']);
$address->appendChild($postal);
$address->appendChild($country);
$address->appendChild($fulladd);

return $doc->saveXML();
```

and my curl POST data code is:-

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?oauth_token=' . $accesstoken;
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 5);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $contact_detail);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

        $curlheader[0] = "Content-Type: application/atom+xml";
        $curlheader[2] = "Content-length:" . strlen($contact_detail);
        $curlheader[1] = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary";
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curlheader);

        $xmlresponse = curl_exec($curl);
```

Here `$contact_detail` is nothing but the XML generated above.
And it create new contact successfully, but it can't add NAME of the contact.

Please suggest me changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to set '**GData-Version:3.0**' in your Authorized request Headers, or specify the current API version in you request URL (?v=3), this may helps.